# List months between a given date range

Tags: templating, datetime

I am trying to list the months (January, Febuary etc) between two dates.
I have a start date: `5/4/2015` and an end date: `9/25/2015`.

Using [range](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html) I am able to return the month numbers, but just can't figure out the correct syntax to convert `5` into `May`.

Here's what I've got so far, maybe there is a better way all together?

**TWIG**

```
{% set startMonth = craft.plugin.getStartDate() %} // returns 5/4/2015
{% set endMonth = craft.plugin.getEndData() %} // returns 9/25/2015

{% for month in range(startMonth, endMonth, 1) %}
    {{ month }}  // returns 5 6 7 8 9
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried doing something like: `{{ month|date('F') }}` but that returns `December` for each result.

I'll eventually need days within this month range, but I am hoping from this I can figure that out.

Comment: Thank you everyone - these are all so great. I wish there was a way to accept all answers!

Answer (score 3):

I made a Craft plugin that simply wraps PHP DatePeriod: ["Date Period plugin for Craft"](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-dateperiod). The plugin provides a `datePeriod` Twig function. It works really simple, your give it a start date, an end date and an interval to create a DatePeriod object.

```
datePeriod( startDate, endDate, interval )
```

This DatePeriod object you can now iterate over to get the dates, recurring at the set interval, over the period spanning your start and end date. By default the interval is set to 1 day, but you can modify that with the (optional) parameter.

```
{% set datePeriod = datePeriod(startDate, endDate, '1 month') %}

{% for month in datePeriod %}
    {{ month|date('F') }}
{% endfor %}
```

To also list the days in between, you would add Craft's `group` filter like so:

```
{% set datePeriod = datePeriod(startDate, endDate) %}

{% for month, daysInMonth in datePeriod|group('{ object|date("F") }') %}
    {{ month }}
    {% for day in daysInMonth %}
        {{ day|date('d') }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there must be a better way, but if you want to also show the days eventually, try this approach (As hinted by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078884/twig-date-loop-each-day-in-a-period), you basically loop through the seconds, in steps of 86400 (= one day)):

```
{% set start = craft.plugin.getStartDate() %} // returns 5/4/2015
{% set end = craft.plugin.getEndData() %} // returns 9/25/2015

{% set currentMonth = null %}
{% for day in range(start | date('U'), end | date('U'), 86400) %}
    {% set month = day | date('F') %} {# create a month variable #}
    {% if month != currentMonth %}
        {{ month }} {# display the month, once #}
        {% set currentMonth = month %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ day | date('d') }} {# display the day #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah - I had looked at the thread you linked to - this is where I was going wrong: `{% if month != currentMonth %}...{%endif%}`

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with a recursive macro and add a day / month to the `startDate` with each iteration:

```
{% macro listDays(startDate, endDate) %}
    {% import _self as self %}

    {% if startDate <= endDate %}
        {{ startDate|date('F-d') }}
        {{ self.listDays(startDate|date_modify('+ 1 day'), endDate) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

And then call it like so:

```
{{ macros.listDays(startDate, endDate) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this macro in my _macros/_utils.html:

```
{% macro monthNameFromNumber(monthNumber) %}
  {# monthNumber will be 00-12. we use that to construct a date string,
     convert it to date and then pick the month name out of that #}
  {{ date('2014-' ~ monthNumber ~ '-01') | date('F') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

You can use it like this:

```
{% import _macros/utils as m_utils %}

{% for month in range(startMonth, endMonth, 1) %}
  {{ m_utils.monthNameFromNumber(month) }}
{% endfor %}
```